# is it possible to make widgets without using fremarker?

Tags: ofbiz

I am working on ofbiz in Netbeans IDE.in ofbiz we make widgets using freemarker templates which renders the webpage but is it possible to make widgets without freemarker and is it possible to add html and css directly in any screens.xml or any xml file if yes then how?

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear from your question what you want to achieve. 
OFBiz widgets internally use freemarker fragments to render the html, if you want to see an implementation w/o freemarker, have a look at org.ofbiz.widget.html package.

If you want to use html/css in you pages, simply use freemarker (with  tags)and write your html/css in the freemarker.

Comment: thank you Bilgin. I added html and css code in freemarker and I made nice webpage.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid using freemarker, then you will need different templating engine, and you need to integrate it.

Yes, you can use html directely inside screen.

```
<decorator-section name="body">
                        <platform-specific>
                            <html>
                                <html-template location="component://practice/webapp/practice/Person.ftl"/>
                            </html>
                        </platform-specific>
                    </decorator-section>
```

https://cwiki.apache.org/OFBIZ/ofbiz-tutorial-a-beginners-development-guide.html

https://cwiki.apache.org/OFBIZ/understanding-the-ofbiz-widget-toolkit.html

Comment: thank you very much.As a beginner it's really helpful for me.